# Why new Date() returns GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)?

Tags: javascript, date, google-apps-script

How can I get UTC current date object? I have no idea why it is Earstern Standard Time. I have never used this time zone in any Google Products.

Input:

```js
function myFunction() {
  const today = new Date();
  console.log(today);
}
```

Output:

Thu Feb 25 2021 22:30:27 GMT-0500 (Eastern Standard Time)

[image: result]

Comment: `new Date()` normally produces an output based on the local time of the computer calling it. Where are **you**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Newly created script uses owner's timezone as the script time zone.

### How to get the script time zone?

```
var timeZone = Session.getScriptTimeZone();
Logger.log(timeZone);
```

### How to change timezone?

**Note:** *You must use the legacy editor to make this work*.

1. If you are using new editor, Select **Use legacy editor**. (You can skip this if you already using legacy editor)
2. In your legacy editor, click **File**
3. Select **Project Properties**
4. Click the drop down list and select a timezone you want
5. Click **Save**
6. Click **Use new editor** and rerun your code

### Example:

**Before changing the time zone:**

[image]

**After changing the time zone:**

[image]

You can also use [formatDate(date, timeZone, format)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#formatdatedate,-timezone,-format) to change the time zone via script.

**Example:**

```
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(), "GMT", "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'");
Logger.log(formattedDate)
```

### Reference:

[getScriptTimeZone()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/session#getScriptTimeZone())

Comment: Wow, this is the perfect answer. I still don't get why the default time zone is Eastern Standard Time. My browser and container spreadsheet uses different time zones. However, the problem is solved. Thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

> By default, JavaScript will use the browser's time zone and display a date as a full text string

refer : [W3Schools](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_dates.asp)

Comment: My browser uses different time zone. So I don't think this is the case.